# 'movie' is not a valid word

Tags: discussion

Now we all know that 'movie' is a valid word. But whenever I type it in this Site (while asking or answering Questions), there is a little "Red" line below it indicating that it's not a valid word. This does not happens when I type the word in MS-Word or anywhere else? Is this a bug in our site/sites?

This happens with both captial 'M' and small 'm'.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post a proper answer, because Gilles closed this question; "Movie" is not a proper word in Britsh English (and if I look at your profile, that's probably what you speak). It is however, a proper word in American English. This site is mainly written in A.E., so it's fine here. But B.E. is explicitly allowed, too.

Answer (score 12):

That's your browser's spell checker, not the site.

Comment: Really? Okay, thanks.

Comment: @myselfpoddar - go to any webmail you have and type the word in the subject or body of email. Does that light up as red?